# What does std::system_error' what(): Lock is not recoverable Abort (core dumped) mean?

Tags: c++, c++11, pthreads, mutex

I am getting this error in a C++ program, and I want to know what it means in order to debug and fix the problem.

```
       std::system_error'
      what():  Lock is not recoverable

Abort (core dumped)
```

I'm working in a project with distributed concurrence, and using a "monitor" made with the `<mutex>` C++ library.

I'm using C++11 and pthreads.

Comment: It means that you've got an exception. You can use a debugger to examine stack trace and variables to find the bug in your code.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds very much like the error code `ENOTRECOVERABLE` of a pthread mutex. To quote the man-page for `pthread_mutexattr_setrobust`

> If a mutex is initialized with the `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST` attribute and its owner dies without unlocking it, any future attempts to call `pthread_mutex_lock(3)` on this mutex will succeed and return `EOWNERDEAD` to indicate that the original owner no longer exists and the mutex is in an inconsistent state.  Usually after `EOWNERDEAD` is returned, the next owner should call `pthread_mutex_consistent(3)` on the acquired mutex to make  it consistent again before using it any further.

> If  the next owner unlocks the mutex using `pthread_mutex_unlock(3)` before making it consistent, the mutex will be permanently unusable and any subsequent attempts to lock it using `pthread_mutex_lock(3)` will fail with the error `ENOTRECOVERABLE`.  The only permitted operation on such a mutex is `pthread_mutex_destroy(3)`.

So this probably occurred when a process or thread holding a mutex died.

The page also mentioned that on Linux, a process calling `execve` without unlocking can also cause this.